# Recursively search for a record attribute and collect into list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, records

Hi I'm trying to get how I would collect the same attibute of a (possibly) deeply nested data structure. The following data types are

```
data PageContent = 
PageElement { content_type :: String
            , element :: String
            , attributes :: Maybe Object
            , services :: Maybe [ServiceRequest]
            , body :: Maybe [PageContent]
            , styles :: Maybe Object
            , scripts :: Maybe Object }
| PageComponent { content_type :: String
                , id :: String
                , tag :: Maybe String
                , args :: Maybe Object
                , services ::Maybe [ServiceRequest]}
| PageConditional { content_type :: String
                  , true :: Maybe [PageContent]
                  , false :: Maybe [PageContent]
                  , condition :: String }
deriving(Show)
```

So in  my case I'm trying to collect all ServiceRequest that are declared. Elements are passed in as a list of [PageContent]. I think it would be perfect to use a recursive function because for example when I hit a PageElement that element could have a _body which has a Maybe [PageContent], so going through the _body of a PageElement should be identical to going through the original [PageContent] list passed in, given that I extract it from Maybe.

I have a hard time figuring out how I would return this as a new list

```
getPageContentServiceRequests :: [PageContent] -> Maybe [ServiceRequest]
```

So I could have no ServiceRequest or I could have a list of 1 or more ServiceRequests. If I do this recursively, would I pass two lists to the function? One with [PageContent] and then an empty list which I could add to recursively while collecting ServiceRequests?

example

```
getPageContentServiceRequests (x:xs) (y:ys) =
    case (isJust (body x)) of
        True -> y : getPageContentServiceRequests fromJust (body x) ys
```

Would this be the correct approach? I feel I understand the recursive concept when I'm working with a list of the same type but not if I have to construct a completely new list with a different type.

Comment: `Maybe` abstracts zero or one, `[]` abstracts arbitrary elements. Are you sure you need both? Do you need to tell `Just []` and `Nothing` apart?

Comment: @Zeta not really. You mean I could have the type :: [PageContent] -> [a]  where [a] is either [ServiceRequest] or [] the empty list?

Comment: Yes, but your `PageComponent` or `PageElement` could have `services :: [ServiceRequest]` instead of `Maybe [ServiceRequest]`.

Comment: @Zeta Ahh I see what you mean. The reason I have Maybe [ServiceRequest] is because it's parsing these information from a yaml file where the services declaration can be present or not. So I guess yes I need to tell it apart. I thought you meant the return type of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Maybe a` is a `Monoid` as long as `a` is a `Monoid`:

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a)
```

Therefore, we can `map` each `PageContent` to a `Maybe [ServiceRequest]` and `mconcat` them.

The `PageElement` has a `services :: Maybe [ServiceRequest]`, but it may also have more `Maybe [ServiceRequest]`s under the `body :: Maybe [PageContent]`.  We can use `getPageContentServiceRequests` on the body, using `>>=` to join the two levels of `Maybe` that would be introduced, and use `<>` (aka `mappend`) to append them with `services`.  We can do the same for `PageComponent` and `PageConditional`:

```
import Data.Monoid

getPageContentServiceRequests :: [PageContent] -> Maybe [ServiceRequest]
getPageContentServiceRequests = mconcat . map getServiceRequests where

  getServiceRequests :: PageContent -> Maybe [ServiceRequest]
  getServiceRequests PageElement { services=services, body=body } =
    services <> (body >>= getPageContentServiceRequests)
  getServiceRequests PageComponent { services=services } =
    services
  getServiceRequests PageConditional { true=true, false=false } =
    (true >>= getPageContentServiceRequests) <>
    (false >>= getPageContentServiceRequests)
```

Comment: thank you very much for this clear and informative answer